# UI-Router Child State For Multiple Parent States

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a project that requires parent routes that are separated, in order to isolate URLs, controllers and API calls.

/boardgames/:id/review/
/boardgames/:id/setup/

The issue I am trying to solve is how to have a common child route, for all of the parent routes?

/boardgames/:id/review/rules/
/boardgames/:id/setup/rules/

Here is a simplified version of the current UI-Router config:

```
    .state('app.frontend.view', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/boardgames/:id',
        views: {
            'page@': {
                templateUrl: 'public/html/game/view/index.html',
                resolve: {},
                controller: 'View'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.frontend.view.review', {
        url: '/review/',
        views: {
            'tab@app.frontend.view': {
                templateUrl: 'public/html/game/tabs/review/index.html',
                resolve: {},
                controller: 'ViewReview'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.frontend.view.setup', {
        url: '/setup/',
        views: {
            'tab@app.frontend.view': {
                templateUrl: 'public/html/game/tabs/setup/index.html',
                resolve: {},
                controller: 'ViewSetup'
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the HTML structure: (public/html/game/view/index.html)

```
<div class='item'>
    <div ui-view='tab'></div>
</div>
```

**ALL IS WORKING UP TO THIS POINT.**

I was thinking of passing another parameter to create a dynamic state... and then chaining the child route:

```
.state('app.frontend.view.{{:path}}', {
    url: '/:path/',
    views: {
        'tab@app.frontend.view': {
            templateUrl: 'public/html/game/tabs/:path/index.html',
            resolve: {},
            controller: ':path' (format :path into friendly name)
        }
    }
})
.state('app.frontend.view.{{:path}}.rules', {
    url: '/rules/',
    views: {
        'rules@app.frontend.view': {
            templateUrl: 'public/html/game/tabs/rules/index.html',
            resolve: {},
            controller: 'ViewRules'
        }
    }
});
```

Is this the best way to go forward?

Answer (score 0):

After researching this topic further, I found that:

1. State naming should be locked in during the config phase.

`.state('app.frontend.view.{{:path}}', {}`

Would equal:

`.state('app.frontend.view.image', {}`

2. The Url would include the parameter '/:path/, templateUrl and controller can all have locked in names and use the parameter differently:

In the router resolve it would be:

```
resolve: {
    tabResolve: ['$stateParams', 'game', function($stateParams, game) {
        return game.show({
            id: $stateParams.id,
            tab: $stateParams.tab
        }).$promise;
    }]
}
```

Only one controller is needed now, since the data being passed in is different for every parameter (review, setup).